# Why doesn't `pivot_wider` work on a `data.table`

Tags: r, data.table, pivot-table, tidyverse, tidyr

A simple example of long to wide pivot:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(data.table)

df <- data.frame(names=letters[1:3],values=1:3)
df %>% pivot_wider(names_from=names,values_from=values)
#works

dt <- data.table(names=letters[1:3],values=1:3)
dt %>% pivot_wider(names_from=names,values_from=values)
Error in data.frame(row = row_id, col = col_id) : 
  arguments imply differing number of rows: 0, 3
```

Why does this error happen?

PS: one fix is to remove the data tableness with `as.data.frame(dt)`.

```
dt %>% as.data.frame %>% pivot_wider(names_from=names,values_from=values)
#works
```

Comment: Because pivot_wider requires a data frame object, but a data.table has a different class, hence you need to either convert your data table to a data frame before pivoting or you'd need to create your piviting pipe in data table synstax directly on the data.table.

Comment: Check point 21 here: https://www.machinelearningplus.com/data-manipulation/datatable-in-r-complete-guide/

Comment: Reported the issue on [GitHub](https://github.com/tidyverse/tidyr/issues/1066). Should be an easy fix.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Manual entry of this function in `tidyr` [mentions only "data frame" without specifying other classes](https://tidyr.tidyverse.org/reference/pivot_wider.html) like tibble or data.table. So addressing your question, function
is either not designed to handle data.table, or there is a bug in `pivot_wider`.

As a workaround you can now use `as.data.frame` (as you already mentioned), if your data is big then possibly `setDF` to avoid extra in-memory copy.

You can also use `data.table` function `dcast` to perform same kind of transformation.

```r
library(tidyr)
library(data.table)

df <- data.frame(names=letters[1:3],values=1:3)
pivot_wider(df, names_from=names,values_from=values)
## A tibble: 1 x 3
#      a     b     c
#  <int> <int> <int>
#1     1     2     3
setDT(df)
dcast(df, .~names, value.var="values")[, ".":=NULL][]
#   a b c
#1: 1 2 3
```

Comment: I think this is some specific case. `pivot_wider` works with `data.table`. `df <- mtcars;
setDT(df); tidyr::pivot_wider(df, names_from = cyl, values_from = mpg)` returns the same output as `tidyr::pivot_wider(mtcars, names_from = cyl, values_from = mpg)`

Comment: Here's the [GitHub issue](https://github.com/tidyverse/tidyr/issues/1066). In essence, [tag:tidyr] calls `dt[col_names]`. Regarding @RonakShah's interesting find, I think starting at [this line](https://github.com/tidyverse/tidyr/blob/501a757bf983a3eb6e82f53173672a92d828236f/R/pivot-wide.R#L224) is why. Some pivots have all vars pivoted whereas others do not. There are two different row counts depending on the method.